# Integral setup, vector calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

**The trajectory of an airplane is given by
the parabola y = −x(x − 10)/10 where x and y are
measured in km. Set-up an integral (with bounds) to
calculate the amount of fuel burned by this airplane
on a single trip (which starts and ends at height y = 0
but for different values of x) if its fuel consumption
is (12 − y) gallons per kilometer traveled, with y the
height of the airplane. DO NOT EVALUATE THE
INTEGRAL.**

I don't have the solutions to practice problems, I was just wondering if it was correct to assume the following solution? Thank You!!!

y = −x(x − 10)/10 
df/dx= (12-y)

For y=0, 
x=0 or x=10

For traveling trip from start to 10 km apart 
f= ∫(12-y)dx from x= 0 to 10

= ∫(limits 0 to 10) (12 +x(x − 10)/10)dx 
=∫(limits 0 to 10) 1/10(120 +x^2 − 10x)dx

Answer (score 1):

you should probably include the vertical motion by replacing $dx$ with

$dl=\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2} =  \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} dx$

so $ \displaystyle  I=\frac{1}{10} \int_0^{10} \left( x^2-10x+120   \right) \sqrt{1+(10-2x)^2} \;\;dx $

Comment: So to find the dx/dy you take the derivative of (12-y) and to find dy/dx you take the derivative of -x(x-10)/10

Comment: I'm just saying that you have to include the vertical movement in the distance travelled - it's not 12-y gallons per horizontal kilometre travelled. the fact that you were asked not to evaluate the integral is a clue that this is what was intended.